# stack api (java) to connect with my application

Tags: stack, stackexchange-api

I am new to stack API.  I want to integrate my application with stack such that i can search something from my application and get response from stack overflow.
Please guide me if it is possible to do and legal.
if yes steps to do

Answer (score 0):

There details about requirements (such as registering your application to get an access key) and API documentation over on Stack Exchange, [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)